# Convert [h]:mm:ss;@ format to Excel number

Tags: php, excel

When I paste 41:30:00 into a cell of Excel, with "General" format option selected, it returns me this decimal: 1,729166667

How do I achieve this decimal through PHP (formula)?

I mean, I want to set the cell with the value of 1,729166667, not 41:30:00 (PHPExcel), because I getting problems with formatting and being able to read it as a value in the Excel file.

Comment: If you're using PHPExcel, then look at the methods in PHPExcel_Shared_Date for converting between human-readable/unix timestamp/DateTime object/Excel serialized timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out.
The number generated from an amount of time, in this case, is represented as a fraction of 24 hours.

So, 12:00:00 will be 0,5 and so on.

I converted the number to seconds, then divided it by 86400 which is 24h in seconds.

Also, used this custom format for PHPExcel to display the time correctly:

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle('C'.$row_start.':E'.$row)
                                        ->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('[h]:mm:ss;@');
```

Comment: To be a bit more specific, when you paste H:m:s into Excel it assumes January 1, 1900 plus the H:m:s portion. The number that displays represents the number of days and portion of days from January 0, 1900 strangely enough. So, for example, if you convert January 2,1900 12:00:00 using the "General" format, it will give you 2.5. If you are only interested in the Time portion, you can drop the number before the period.